# Fragment contents are overlapping on ActionBar in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Why is the `Fragment` Layout overlapping the `ActionBar` like this

1. `FirstFragment`

   ```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".FirstFragment">

   <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment" />
   ```

   [image]
2. `SecondFragment`

   ```
   <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@string/hello_second_fragment" />
   ```

   [image]

`activity_navigation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`app_bar_navigation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sup.slideup.Navigation">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Using `KitKat` Device.

Comment: post your activity xml...

Comment: @RishadAppat: Take a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to maintain the non-LinearLayout in your Activity layout you need to set a `layout_marginTop` on the `FrameLayout` that holds your `Fragment`. In your `app_bar_navigation.xml`:

```
...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />
...
```

Comment: `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` is perfect... Thanks